# Adding text of variable size to the corner of an image so that it always fits

Tags: graphics, string-manipulation, image

I have an image for example:

```
img = Import[
  "http://ultraimg.com/images/2016/07/29/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-\
Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg"]
```

I'm creating a text graphics object:

```
string = "a test string";
gObj = Graphics[
   Text[Style[string, FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 
     White, Background -> Black]]];
```

and add it to the image in the left bottom corner:

```
picFinal = ImageCompose[img, gObj, {60, 10}]
```

Now when I use a longer string:

```
string = "a test string that is a bit longer ";
```

this results in the string not fitting. But I need to add strings with variable sizes to the left bottom corner as well. How can I adapt the position of my string such that it always has a specified distance from the left bottom corner and adapt dynamically to the size of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is the automatic rasterisation of the text.  When you give a `Graphics` object to an image based function, it automatically converts it to an image.

```
ImageAssemble[{{
   Graphics[Text@"a test string", Background -> LightGray], 
   Graphics[Text@"a test string that is a bit longer", Background -> LightGreen]
}}]
```

[image: 1]

Which is fine, but with the big border you lose control of where the text starts.  However if you explicitly `Rasterize` the text, *without* making it into  `Graphics`, it's more compact and predictable:

```
gObj = Rasterize[
  Text[Style[string, FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 
    White, Background -> Black]], Background -> None]
```

[image: 2]

Then you can use `ImageCompose` parameters to good effect to always get it in the left bottom:

```
ImageCompose[img, gObj, {5, 0}, {Left, Bottom}]
```

[image: 3]

Comment: I see, thank you!